# getting error message while declare a constant

Tags: php

i define the constant once in my file `define ("site_name",'Unlimited Naira');` and call it in the scrip like `constant("site_name");` but am getting this error

> Notice: Constant site_name already defined in
>   C:\xampp2\htdocs\ponzi\setting.php on line 2

although it output the answer correctly but still getting error message any solution or if it have been mention some where please give me the link as appropriate

Comment: just call it like so `site_name`. it's saying you are trying to redefine it..

Comment: Just refer with `site_name`

Comment: *"and call it in the scrip like constant("site_name");"* - that isn't how constants are called/used. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php

Answer (score 0):

You can either echo it using

```
<?php

define ("site_name","Unlimited Naira");
echo constant("site_name");
?>
```

or simply echo the constant as,

```
<?php

define ("site_name","Unlimited Naira");
echo site_name;
?>
```